# Does the movement of things in the universe will cease one day?

Tags: universe, time, kinematics

To start or change the movement, we need a force. This force, according to Newton's second law, is variation of quantity of motion from the object per unit of time.Therefore, if the variation does not exist, the amount of movement of objects is conserved.This conclusion allows enunciate the Newton's first law as follows: The amount of movement of an object is preserved if the resultant of the forces that act on it is null. So, Does the movement of things in the universe will cease one day?

Comment: Hi Igor - this question isn't particularly clear. Is there some reason you've been led to believe all movement in the universe will cease one day? Or is there some reason you've been led to believe it won't? Could you explain your motivation in more detail? Also, make sure your actual question is in the body, not just in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Making predictions like these are impossible to be honest.

Furthermore it strongly depends on what you mean by movement ceasing. Assuming a non-collapsing Universe and the validity of QM the answer would be No. The uncertainty principle alone would be enough to justify this.